# How long would I need to wait before bumping, if that's allowed at all?

Tags: support

If I posted a question (which received no comments or responses), and a single up vote, **how long would I need to wait before bumping it, if that's allowed at all**?

I would post the link to my question but then again it I don't want people getting the wrong idea.

Comment: Don't bump it. Please read [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: It's not difficult to find a link to your only [su] question ;)

Comment: I never implied it was a frantic help desk. Nor am I taking it personally. I got my answer already about bumping but thank you for the input there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Bumping" for the sake of bumping is generally frowned upon here.

You can do a few things - *enhance* the question with more details (though clearly, you can only do so much - don't add inane details or minor edits to bump. We like edits to be substantial) or offer a bounty if you have enough reputation.